# Setting Up An FTP Server: IIS 7.5

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I think I might have incorrectly configured an ftp site (it's my first time setting one of these up) in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.  The error that I keep getting is "User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible."  This happens when I:

1. Open up a Windows command prompt.
2. Type `ftp localhost`.
3. Enter the user name and password for the Windows account that was configured specifically for this purpose.

I gave full control permissions to the user for the physical folder which the ftp site references.  I also have the site configured for Basic Authentication (using the aforementionad Windows user name and password).  At any rate, I'm kind of lost at this point...  Any help on how I might troubleshoot this would be very much appreciated!

Oh, I also checked to make sure that the length of the computer name of the server is indeed less than 15 characters long (I read on another forum somewhere that this sometimes causes an issue with ftp log ins).

Thanks!

Andrew

Comment: Why was I voted down?  I won't take offense...  Just wondering...

Comment: This isn't a programming question, that's probably why.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Okay, thanks for letting me know Randolph!  I'll try a different forum...

Comment: The proper forum for this is http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, apparently I had to add an authorization rule to IIS.  This can be done by selecting the FTP site in the left pane in IIS manager and clicking the Add Authorization Rule icon.  Then I just added the specific user, and it worked.  See [this posting](http://forum.dotnetpanel.com/forums/p/4520/22287.aspx).

Andrew